# Editing content in txt files using batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm needing some help with a content editing 
My goal is to use a batch script and for it to find all `id_?` found inside txt files 
and change ever letter from Uppercase to Lowercase

This is my script

EditFiles.bat

```
@echo off

set "replace=id_A"
set "replaced=id_a"

set "source=2Folder\File5002014.txt"
set "target=3Folder\File50020141.txt"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %source%\*.txt') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      if defined line set "line=!line:%replace%=%replaced%!"
      echo(!line!
   )
) > %target%
endlocal
```

I managed to get it to find a pattern 
the script above does work and will edit the content in a txt file but will only edit the matching name 
I did try to change it to read any file but can't figure it out

I have over `100 txt files` and all have different `id_?` content 
what I need this to do is

```
FIND
id_AaPPle
id_A
id_BeRRy
id_B
id_CoRn
id_c...etc


REPLACE
id_apple
id_a
id_berry
id_b
id_corn
id_c...etc
```

Keep in mind I have over 100 different words after the id_?

and I need it to scan any txt file found in 2Folder and only edit the files inside the 2 Folder

This is what I tried and it failed My first attempt was to make it edit the files only in the 2Folder

EditFiles.bat

```
@echo off

set "replace=id_a"
set "replaced=id_A"

set "source=2Preparing\File5002014.txt"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %source%\*.txt') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      if defined line set "line=!line:%replace%=%replaced%!"
      echo(!line!
   )
) >> %source%
endlocal
```

the only way I could figure out how to edit more `id_?` was to repeat the codes like this

```
@echo off

set "replace1=id_A"
set "replaced1=id_a"

set "source=2Preparing\File5002014.txt"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %source%\*.txt') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      if defined line set "line=!line:%replace1%=%replaced1%!"
      echo(!line!
   )
) > %target%
endlocal

set "replace2=id_aPPle"
set "replaced2=id_apple"

set "source=2Preparing\File5002014.txt"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %source%\*.txt') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      if defined line set "line=!line:%replace2%=%replaced2%!"
      echo(!line!
   )
) > %target%
endlocal
```

OK this set

```
set "replace1=id_A"
set "replaced1=id_a"
```

is to find every `id_A` and change it to `id_a` now not every word has mixed upper and lower case letters 
For example I have the word `id_Grapes` here I just have to worry about the `G`

So I would make a script to do this

```
set "replace1=id_G"
set "replaced1=id_g"
```

Any help with this would be great

Thank you

Here is how it looks inside my files

```
File 1.txt
{
      "upma": "id_Apples",
      "upnn": 20,
      "upfb": true,
      "upcu": false
}
{
      "upma": "id_APpleS",
      "upnn": 25,
      "upfb": false,
      "upcu": false
}

File 2.txt
{
      "upma": "id_BeRRy",
      "upnn": 10,
      "upfb": true,
      "upcu": false
}
{
      "upma": "id_BerRy",
      "upnn": 20,
      "upfb": false,
      "upcu": false
}

File 3.txt
{
      "upma": "id_Corn",
      "upnn": 29,
      "upfb": true,
      "upcu": false
}
{
      "upma": "id_Corn",
      "upnn": 40,
      "upfb": false,
      "upcu": false
}
```

Pretty much this is repeated many times per file.txt

My results

```
File 1.txt
{
      "upma": "id_apples",
      "upnn": 20,
      "upfb": true,
      "upcu": false
}
{
      "upma": "id_apples",
      "upnn": 25,
      "upfb": false,
      "upcu": false
}

File 2.txt
{
      "upma": "id_berry",
      "upnn": 10,
      "upfb": true,
      "upcu": false
}
{
      "upma": "id_berry",
      "upnn": 20,
      "upfb": false,
      "upcu": false
}

File 3.txt
{
      "upma": "id_corn",
      "upnn": 29,
      "upfb": true,
      "upcu": false
}
{
      "upma": "id_corn",
      "upnn": 40,
      "upfb": false,
      "upcu": false
}
```

Comment: Please post a few line of your source data and expected results. For instance, can `id_?` be anywhere in the data, have you got non-alphamerics in the data? Need to preserve empty lines? Is format consistent in files?

Comment: @Magoo all files have the same amount of spacing where the id_ is located and it's repeated at least `21 times` per file, and that is the only `id_` found in the file and their are no Numbers only letters - Thank you for you time

Comment: Batch is the wrong tool for this task. You need something with REGEX capability, like Powershell, or if you are stuck with `cmd`, [jrepl.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) is a good tool.

Comment: @Stephan Yes, I am aware but I am making a small choice menu and I want to be able to add it to the menu script, so when I press option 4 it runs it

Comment: in order to keep the script I have can you help me fix it to where it edits only the 2Folder and reads any txt file, no target folder, if I have to double up the scripts I'm find with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for directory names are those
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "alphabet=a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"
SET "indent=      "

FOR %%e IN ("%sourcedir%\F*") DO (
 rem filename in %%e
 (
 FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%y iN ("%%e") DO (
  rem raw line in %%y
  FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=: " %%b iN ("%%y") DO (
   IF "%%~b"=="upma" (
    CALL :lower %%c
    ECHO %indent%%%b: "!lowered!",
   ) ELSE ECHO %%y
  )
 )
 )>"%destdir%\%%~nxe"
)

GOTO :EOF

:lower
SET "lowered=%~1"
FOR %%z IN (%alphabet%) DO SET "lowered=!lowered:%%z=%%z!"
GOTO :eof
```

Note that I've used a filemask of `F*` for testing purposes

The destination directory must be different from the source directory.

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

I've used the data format in the examples to construct this solution.

**Missing information:** No indication of what happens should `id_?` contains spaces - assumed does not occur.

Outer loop: `%%e` is set to each filename to process.

Next loop : each line of `%%e` assigned to `%%y` in turn.

Next loop : each line is tokenised using <kbd>:</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> if the first token without quotes (`%%~b`) is `upma`, then convert the remainder-of-line (`%%c`) to lower-case, otherwise just regurgitate the raw line read.

The data `echo`ed from the innermost loop is gathered by the (parenthesised next level code) into yje output file, in a different directory, using the name and extension of the original file.

The lower-case conversion routine uses the charateristic of the string in `%%c` which will be of the form `"id_SomEString",`.

The `call` eats the comma because it's seen as a separator by the `call`ed routine.

Then - assign `lowered` to the dequoted string and process it using `set "var=!var:character1=character2!"` for each lower-case alphabetic character. Delayed expansion because we are modifying the variable in the loop and the substitution operation is case-insensitive for `character1` and uses `character2` literally.

Naturally, since `id_` is already lower-case and non-alphabetic, it's unaffected by the routine.

Comment: THANK YOU - I had to add a few other scripts to make it work but I got it, I needed to add a mover script to move the files from `Target back to Source`, because I have another script that merges the files together into 1 file from the Target folder, 

so it starts from Source first by editing the content to target and then it moves target to source, and then your script edits source to target and then my merger ready target folder